# How to set up two wifi access-points on one wifi device on Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: server, raspberrypi, dhcp, netplan, static-ip

So I want to set up Wi-Fi on the raspberry Ubuntu server, but I need to get it to connect to two access-points, one needs a static IP and the other one dhcp4.

This is my network-config file that I used to set up the Raspberry Pi:

```
version: 2
ethernets:
  eth0:
    dhcp4: true
    optional: true
wifis:
  wlan0:
    addresses:
      [192.168.1.201/24]
    gateway4: 192.168.1.1
    nameservers:
      addresses: [192.168.1.1]
    optional: true
    access-points:
      "WIFI-NAME":
        password: "WIFI-PW"
```

I want to add this access-point:

```
wifis:
  wlan0:
    dhcp4: true
    optional: true
    access-points:
      "CIA_VAN":
        password: "123456789"
```

If it is possible the second connection should have a higher priority.

Comment: Won't work. Sorry.

Comment: Does that mean, that I have to make a new netplan every time, I switch wifi?

Comment: You can check https://netplan.io/reference/ and https://netplan.io/examples/ for possible ideas.